# $o(z) = 28$, what is $o(z^{16})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, roots-of-unity

I have this math question that I am kind of stuck on.

> Suppose that $o(z) = 28$, what is the order of the element $z^{16}$?

From this information I know that $o(z) = 28$ means that $z^{28} = 1$... How can I use that to find $o(z^{16})$? Thanks.

Comment: The proof-writing tag is for advice on clear presentation of a proof that you have in mind. If you don't have any proof yet, don't use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that $o(z)=28$ gives you that $z^n = e$ if and only if $n = 28k$ for some $k\in {0,1,2,...}$, agreed? So you need to find the smallest $m$ such that $16m$ is divisible by $28$, i.e. least common multiple of $28$ and $16$ divided by $16$.

Comment: Ok, so the answer to your question is $112$. So would the order be $7$? $\frac{112}{16}$?

Comment: @KFS, that's right! Do you understand why it is so?

Comment: Yeah, I understand that since $o(z) = 28$, we know $z^{28} = 1$. This means that only $z^{28\cdot m}$ will equal one, and $z^{16\cdot 7}$ = $z^{28\cdot 4}$, so the answer will be $1$.

Comment: @KFS, yeah, $(z^{16})^7 = z^{16\cdot 7} = z^{28\cdot 4} = (z^{28})^4 = 1^4=1$, so $(z^{16})^7= 1$ and this is false for any smaller power than $7$. This means that $o(z^{16}) = 7$

Answer (score 2):

If $o(x)=n$, then $o(x^m)=o(x^d)$ where $d=(n,m)$.

Answer (score 1):

The order of $u = z^4$ is $7$, and you're asked to find the order of $u^4$. The group generated by $u$ has prime order, so it is cyclic. As a result, all of its powers $u^k$ for $1 \leq k \leq 6$ will generate the whole group. Hence $u^4$ has order $7$ too.